# A new sum that equals $-\frac12 \ln (\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, summation, closed-form

(See **EDIT**)

I found this result while working another problem in two slightly different directions and it kind of took me by surprise.

$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln4n}{4n-1}-\frac{2}{\left(4n-1\right)\left(4n+1\right)}\sum_{k=1}^{4n}\left(-1\right)^{k}k\ln k\right)
\\
=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-&\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln\left(4n-2\right)}{4n-3}-\frac{2}{\left(4n-3\right)\left(4n-1\right)}\sum_{k=1}^{4n-2}\left(-1\right)^{k}k\ln k\right)
\end{align}
$$

The only difference between the summation expressions is a shift in the index $n$ by $1/2$.

1. Is there a neat way to prove it? (I feel that explaining the long process that brought me here would dilute the question. I wonder if there is a straight-forward solution starting with one of the sums.)
2. Are there other sums that have general ways to be expressed in terms of themselves with a non-integer shift of the index?
3. Extra: Can we find closed forms for the sums above?

---

**EDIT:**

After seeing the comments, I realized the obvious fact that my main question is equivalent to proving

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\ln2n}{2n-1}-\frac{2}{\left(2n-1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left(-1\right)^{k}k\ln k\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
$$

However I am also interested in finding a closed form for

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{\ln2n}{2n-1}-\frac{2}{\left(2n-1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left(-1\right)^{k}k\ln k\right)
$$

Comment: Can you say more about how you came to this result? Maybe all the detail is a holdback, but I find myself curious about the origin of these exotic expressions.

Comment: They have shifted the index $n$ by $2$, not by $1/2$.  The claim is that the new first term accounts for the $n=1$ and $n=2$ terms of the original sum and the remaining sum accounts for all the other terms.  I have not tried to justify the claim.